# ssrs parameter and applying blank value

Tags: reporting-services

I'm fairly new to SSRS, and I'm coming across a small glitch.
I have set three parameters to the report: x, y, and date. I allowed x and y to be blank value ("") by checking off the box under value in parameter properties.

When I try to search just x and date however, the report returns blank with just the headers. Same thing for y and date. It's only when I completely fill out the three parameters that the report shows up. Can anyone tell me why my blank value for both x and y parameters is not working?

Comment: Cross check your Query to get result set based on X & Y; If possible share your script;

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share any part of the script, but I will cross check the query again.

Comment: OK, no problem please make sure your query has condition like (<XField> = @X OR @X='') AND (<YField> = @Y OR @Y='')

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your filtering criteria in query:

```
WHERE (field1 = @x OR @x = '') AND (field2 = @y OR @y = '')
```